# Generate XML sub items using iteration

Tags: ruby

I want to use this Ruby code to generate XML file with 10 terminals:

```
module WriteXML  
 def write_data_xml

  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
   xml.genesis {
    xml.terminals {

/// create here some loop to iterate
         xml.terminal {
         xml.name "PPRO_Terminal"
         xml.type "ppro"
         xml.credentials {
          xml.username 'user1'
          xml.password 'passwd1'
          xml.token '5e36e51de2dde626804a8772dc26238c4d722bbc'
         }
        }}
////////
       }
  end
  puts builder.to_xml
  file = File.new("credentials.xml", "w")

  File.open('credentials.xml', 'w') do |file|
   file << builder.to_xml
  end
 end
end
```

How I can use iteration in order to save code when I want to create many terminals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where you keep the data that identify these terminals, is that in a table ? Then you could do something like this

```
def write_data_xml credential

  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
   xml.genesis {
    xml.terminals {
     xml.terminal {
     xml.name credential.name
     xml.type credential.type
     xml.credentials {
      xml.username credential.username
      xml.password credential.password
      xml.token credential.token
     }
    }}
   }
  end
  File.open("credentials.xml", "a+") { |file| file.write builder.to_xml}
 end
end
```

Suppose you use activerecord you could then

```
Credentials.each do |credential|
  write_data_xml credential
end
```

If no table, you could use an array of structs where you gather the needed data.

EDIT on request of the OP, here a version that doesn't follow the single responsibility principle

```
def write_data_xml 

  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
   xml.genesis {
    xml.terminals {
      Credentials.each do |credential|
        xml.terminal {
        xml.name credential.name
        xml.type credential.type
        xml.credentials {
         xml.username credential.username
         xml.password credential.password
         xml.token credential.token
       }
      end
    }}
   }
  end
  File.write("credentials.xml", builder.to_xml)
 end
end
```

EDIT2

here an example of how to use this with an array of structs since there is no database yet

```
Credentials = []
Credential = Struct.new(:name, :type, :username, :password, :token)
Credentials << Credential.new('PPRO_Terminal', 'ppro', 'user1', 'passwd1', '5e36e51de2dde626804a8772dc26238c4d722bbc')
Credentials << Credential.new( 'PPRO_Terminal2', 'ppro', 'user2', 'passwd2', '...')

p Credentials
[#<struct Credential name="PPRO_Terminal", type="ppro", username="user1", password="passwd1", token="5e36e51de2dde626804a8772dc26238c4d722bbc">, #<struct Credential name="PPRO_Terminal2", type="ppro", username="user2", password="passwd2", token="...">]
```

NB at least, create this outside of the method

Comment: @Peter, it's better to not put everythig in one big method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), even the writing to the file would be better out of the methods, which optimally just would return the xml string. Anyway if you don't care you can introduce my loop in the place you pointed out in your edit. it is also not clear if you want all of the xml in one file or one file for each terminal

Comment: I want everything into one file. Can you update your answer so that with one look I can generate terminals into tag terminals?

Comment: And one more last thing. Can you give me some example How I can insert some test data into Credentials so that when there is a loop to generate the XML with several terminals.

Comment: thats' where I started my answer with, it depends of where you keep your data, do you allready have a source or do you have to create one and fill everything in ?

Comment: I have to create source data. Currently this is only proof of a concept.